# Protractor not able to move price slider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, selenium, protractor

I am new to protractor, trying to test price slider which may sort products based on provided price range, i could not able to drag the slider(min point) using protractor.  how to move the slider?

**Html**

```
<span _ngcontent-serverapp-c119="" ngxsliderhandle="" class="ngx-slider-span ngx-slider-pointer ngx-slider-pointer-min" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" role="slider" tabindex="0" aria-orientation="" aria-label="" aria-labelledby="" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuetext="10" aria-valuemin="10" aria-valuemax="100" style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible; left: 0px;"></span>
```

**Slider Image**
[image]

I tried with

```
    const priceTogggle = element(
        by.xpath(
            '//span[@class="ngx-slider-span ngx-slider-pointer ngx-slider-pointer-min"]'
        )
    );

browser.actions().dragAndDrop(priceTogggle,{x:100,y:0}).mouseUp().perform();  
and   
browser.actions().mouseMove(priceTogggle).mouseDown().mouseMove({x:100,y:0 }).mouseUp().perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use

```
     /**
     * Drags first element to the second one. The destination can either be an elementFinder or an offset in pixels
     * @param    {ElementFinder}        $element
     * @param    {(ElementFinder|{x: number, y: number})}       $destination
     * @returns  {promise.Promise}
     */
    let dragAndDrop = ($element, $destination) => browser
            .actions()
            .mouseMove($element)
            .perform()
            .then(() =>
                browser
                    .actions()
                    .mouseDown($element)
                    .perform()
            )
            .then(() =>
                browser
                    .actions()
                    .mouseMove($destination)
                    .perform()
            )
            .then(() =>
                browser
                    .actions()
                    .mouseUp()
                    .perform()
            );
```

And then call

```
await dragAndDrop($leftGrip, {x: 10, y: 0});
```

But `x` might need to be negative depending on direction you're moving to

Comment: I'm sure it does work for me. So problem is in your locator probably. Maybe you need to drag another element

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with Protractor. However, if you can send me link to a sample site on which the slider is implemented, i can try with selenium-webdriver java.

In the meantime, you can look at the code in my answer to the below  question to see if it helps you.

[Issue for Trip Advisor 5-star rating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60135408/unable-to-find-the-xpath-of-star-using-selenium-java/60137480#60137480)